# What's the way to add decimal number to SQL that replicate in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I already tried with `decimal(10,4)` and `float` in the SQL but after I updated my Database model the EF treat

```
decimal(10,4) as a Decimal in C#
float as a Double in C#
```

witch for me it's great, but the Model Validation always fail

[image]

and it's not because I'm using `.` instead of `,`

[image]

> What should I do so the validation can run smoothly?

I know I can avoid this using a **ModelView** in between the View and the Model, but I just want to know how to do things right.

Comment: In which type does your Efficiency filed (for example) was defined in your model?

Comment: As said above, as `Decimal` and as `Double`, the validation errors are the same :-/

Comment: When you debug it - can you verify the exception is thrown when inserting the entity? I want to be sure this exception relates to the entity framework.

Comment: @Naor, that validation you see in the 1st image is the Model validation, as the jQuery validation sends it correctly, in my action I get `0` instead `675240.72` for the `Turnover` field (and all fields that the validation throws an error). My guess would be the use of `.` instead of `,` but that should be converted automatically in the Model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the problem, it's not me... it's .NET really :)

> http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx