# How can I get a double from the View into My Model?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

This is weird and I'm being on this for a couple days with no more ideas.

Even asked before with no results as well

> [What's the way to add decimal number to SQL that replicate in EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130760/whats-the-way-to-add-decimal-number-to-sql-that-replicate-in-ef)

I have my simple **Model** like this

```
public class SalesModelView
{
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }

    public DateTime SaleDate { get; set; }

    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public double Sales { get; set; }
    public double Treatments { get; set; }

    public double Turnover { get; set; }
    public double TurnoverHour { get; set; }
    public double Efficiency { get; set; }
}
```

And the **HTML** is scaffolded as **Create** containing the trouble input as

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sales)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sales)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sales)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Treatments)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Treatments)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Treatments)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Turnover)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Turnover)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Turnover)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TurnoverHour)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TurnoverHour)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TurnoverHour)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Efficiency)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Efficiency)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Efficiency)
</div>
```

When I try to add an `integer`, it **assumes correctly**, but when I add a `decimal` value, it just **won't pass** back into my `controller`.

> **What am I missing?**

I even tried to set the `CultureInfo` to the correct country, but no luck

JQuery Validation works fine btw.

[original image for better viewing](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2011-05-28_1046.png)

http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2011-05-28_1046.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write a custom model binder.

See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx